# Best way to register all subclasses

Tags: python-3.x, class, subclass, decorator, metaclass

I am currently developing a piece of software where the I have class instamces that are generated from dictionaries. The way these dictionariea file are structured is as follows:

```
layer_dict = {
    "layer_type": "Conv2D",
    "name": "conv1",
    "kernel_size": 3,
    ...
}
```

Then, the following code is ran

```
def create_layer(layer_dict):
    LayerType = getattr(layers, layer_dict['layer_type']
    del layer_dict['layer_type']
    return LayerType(**layer_dict)
```

Now, I want to support the creation of new layer types (by subclassing the `BaseLayer` class). I've thought of a few ways to do this and thought I'd ask which way is best and why as I don't have much experience developing software (finishing an MSc in comp bio).

**Method 1: Metaclasses**
The first method I thought of was to have a metaclass that registers every subclass of `BaseLayer` in a dict and do a simple lookup of this dict instead of using getattr.

```
class MetaLayer(type)
    layers = {}
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        if name in MetaLayer.layers:
            raise ValueError('Cannot have more than one layer with the same name')
        MetaLayer.layers[name] = cls
```

**Benefit**: The metaclass can make sure that no two classes have the same name. The user doesn't need to think about anything but subclassing when creating new layers.
**Downside**: Metaclasses are difficult to understand and often frowned upon

**Method 2: Traversing the `__subclasses__` tree**

The second method I thought of was to use the `__subclassess__` function of `BaseLayer` to get a list of all subclasses, then create a dict with `Layer.__name__` as keys and `Layer` as values. See example code below:

```
def get_subclasses(cls):
    """Returns all classes that inherit from `cls`
    """
    subclasses = {
        sub.__name__: sub for sub in cls.__subclasses__()
    }

    subsubclasses = (
        get_subclasses(sub) for sub in subclasses.values()
    )
    subsubclasses = {
        name: sub for subs in subsubclasses for name, sub in subs.items()
    }
    return {**subclasses, ** subsubclasses}
```

**Benefit:** Easy to explain how this works.
**Downside:** We might end up with two layers having the same name.

**Method 3: Using a class decorator**
The final method is my favourite as it doesn't hide any implementation details in a metaclass, and still manages to prevent multiple classes with the same name.

Here the layers module has a global variable named `layers` and a decorator named `register_layer`, which simply adds the decorated classes to the `layers` dict. See code below.

```
layers = {}
def register_layer(cls):
    if cls.__name__ in layers:
        raise ValueError('Cannot have two layers with the same name')
    layers[cls.__name__] = cls
    return cls
```

**Benefit:** No metaclasses and no way of having two layers with the same name.
**Downside:** Requires a global variable, which is often frowned upon.

So, my question is, which method is preferable? And more importantly, why?

Answer (score 13):

Actually - that is the kind of things metaclases are designed for. As you can see from the options you stated above, it is the simpler and more straightforward design.

They are sometimes "frowned upon" because of two things: (1) people don't understand then and don't care for understanding; (2) people misuse then when they are actually not needed; (3) they are hard to combine - so if any of your classes is to be used with a mixn that have a different metaclass (say abc.ABC), you have also to produce a combining metaclass.

## Method 4: `__init_subclass__`

Now, that said, from Python 3.6, there is a new feature that can cover your usecase without the need for metaclasses: the [class `__init_subclass__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init_subclass__): 
it is called as a classmethod on the *base* class when subclasses of it are created.

All you need is to write a proper `__init_subclass__` method on your `BaseLayer` class and have all the benefits you'd have from the implementation in the metaclasses and none of the downsides

Answer (score 2):

Like you, I like the class decorator approach as it is more readable.

You can avoid using a global variable by making the class decorator itself a class, and making `layers` a class variable instead. You can also avoid possible name collision by joining the target class' name with its module name:

```
class register_layer:
    layers = {}
    def __new__(cls, target):
        cls.layers['.'.join((target.__module__, target.__name__))] = target
        return target
```

Comment: My problem with this approach is that to get a layer I need to write `layers.register_layers.layers[layer_dict['layer_type']` whenever I create a new layer and I don't particularly like that approach. However, I might create a class with a __call__ function that I use.

Comment: I think you might have a typo here and meant to type `register_layers.layers[layer_dict['layer_type']]` rather than `layers...`. I didn't use a `__call__` method because I thought accessing `register_layer.layers` is quite trivial. But if you prefer a getter function then you surely can replace my `__new__` method with a `__call__` method instead.